# When calculating the eigen values of a matrix, can we calculate the determinant at anytime to find them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any way to calculate the eigen values of the following matrix?

I'm going made...

\begin{pmatrix}
   128/3 & -16/3 & -16/3 \\
   -16/3 & 68/3 & 44/3 \\
-16/3 & 44/3 & 68/3
\end{pmatrix}

I did:

\begin{pmatrix}
   (128/3 - \lambda)X_1& -16/3X_2 & -16/3X_3 \\
   -16/3 X_1 & (68/3-\lambda) X_2 & 44/3X_3 \\
-16/3 & 44/3 & (68/3-\lambda)X_3
\end{pmatrix}

And I get lost in unbeliveable complex equations...

\begin{pmatrix}
-16/3 & 44/3 & (68/3-\lambda)X_3\\
   -16/3 X_1 & (68/3-\lambda) X_2 & 44/3X_3 \\
   (128/3 - \lambda)X_1& -16/3X_2 & -16/3X_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}

$\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 11 & 51 -\lambda \\
0 & 40- \lambda & \lambda -40\\
0 &11(24-\lambda) -16 & (51 -\lambda)(24-\lambda) -16
\end{pmatrix}$

Should I calculate the determinant there?
\begin{align}
&\begin{array}{|ccc|}
-4 & 11 & 51 -\lambda \\
0 & 40- \lambda & \lambda -40\\
0 &11(24-\lambda) -16 & (51 -\lambda)(24-\lambda) -16
\end{array}\\
&=-4((40-\lambda)((51 -\lambda)(24-\lambda) -16) - (\lambda -40)(11(24-\lambda) -16))\\
&=-4(40-\lambda)((51 -\lambda)(24-\lambda) -16+ 11(24-\lambda) -16)\\
&=...?
\end{align}

If you have also a ling to some tips such as the sum of the lines or the columns or how to find an annulator polynom, I would be very glad!

Comment: It might help to factor $\tfrac{4}{3}$ out of the matrix. The eigenvalues of $\tfrac{4}{3}A$ will just be the eigenvalues of $A$ multiplied by $\tfrac{4}{3}$, and the eigenvectors will be the same.

Comment: After factoring out $\frac{4}{3}$, you will need to calculate the characteristic polynomial $\det(A-\lambda I)$ of the 'easier' matrix $A$ and find its roots.